# docker secret workflow in mysql container

Tags: mysql

I'm new to docker and want to try to use docker secrets on Swarm with a MySql container.

I launch MySql with docker-compose.yml. And use a .sql script here :

I'm in docker-swarm on debian with latest versions. I created secrets in CLI with echo "password" | docker-secret create "secret" -

And the script is here :

```css
I'm in docker-swarm on debian with latest versions. I created secrets in CLI with echo "password" | docker-secret create "secret" -

And the script is here :

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mailserver
  CHARACTER SET = 'utf8mb4';

USE mailserver;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_domains` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

USE mailserver;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
 FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES virtual_domains(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

USE mailserver;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_aliases` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `source` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `destination` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES virtual_domains(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE USER 'mailadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY $("/run/secrets/mysql_mailadmin_passwd");
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mailserver`.* TO 'mailadmin'@'%';

CREATE USER 'mailuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY $("/run/secrets/mysql_mailuser_passwd");
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mailserver`.* TO 'mailuser'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

a user create statement, placed in a `script.sql`file passed to entrypoint. The file creates successfully database, tables but fails with users due to secret.

I tried to use `cat $("/run/secrets/mysql_mailadmin_passwd")` in the script

```
CREATE USER 'mailadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY XXXXXXXXXXXXX ;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mailserver`.* TO 'mailadmin'@'%';
```

After a lot of tries, logs keep saying i have an `error in my sql syntax.

Comment: Can you explain more? How your docker looks like? And what is             your script?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: `cat /run/secrets/mysql_mailadmin_passwd` what does it print?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 33: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/run/secrets/mysql_mailadmin

And secret is passed in clear text : when I log in the container, I can cat it from shell and it displays the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar approach as the [one described in here](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/mariadb-galera-swarm/blob/master/start.sh#L155-L170):

In a `start.sh` shell script (executed as a `CMD` by your docker image), you create/complete your bootstrap sql script:

```
    cat >/tmp/bootstrap.sql <<EOF
...
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'root'@'localhost';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
EOF
...

MYSQL_MODE_ARGS+=" --init-file=/tmp/bootstrap.sql"
```

With, in our case:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=cat $("/run/secrets/mysql_mailadmin_passwd")
```

Of course, all this assumes that you actually [have created the secret beforehand](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#defining-and-using-secrets-in-compose-files).

Comment: OK I see what you mean. I'm more interested in the process of using docker-secrets than environment variables.

The 2 users are not root. Root password is correctly set with env variable. 

For the others i hesitated a lot but it's still unclear for me to inject docker-secrets in shell and .sql, there should be a way to do it

Comment: @user9276118 this script is an *example*: do adapt it for your users.

Comment: @user9276118 entrypoint will work too, provided you launch a script similar to the start.sh I describe.